# Button inside input (HTML/CSS)

Tags: html, css

I want my button to be inside of the text input. Like this:

[image]

This is my code:

```css
input {
        background: #8196aa;
        border: 0;
        border-radius: 10px;
        color: white;
        padding: 20px;

        &:focus {
            outline: none;
        }

        &::placeholder {
            color: white;
        }
    }

    button {
        background: #16bdae;
        border: 0;
        border-radius: 7px;
        color: white;
        padding: 15px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="pt-site-footer__submit">
  <input type="email" placeholder="Your e-mailadress">
  <button>LOGIN</button>
</div>
```

I hope someone has an answer for this.
(other answers on Stack Overflow didn't help me out)

Comment: You can't. `input`s are replaced elements and cannot have children. Try styling the wrapping div instead.

Comment: So, can you explain how the input in the image is made?

Comment: It's your image, that's on you. Like I said, style the wrapping div to LOOK like it's all one thing.

Comment: You can do it using `position: absolute`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input {
  background: #8196aa;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}

input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

input::placeholder {
  color: white;
}

button {
  background: #16bdae;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 7px;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  top: 5px;
}

.pt-site-footer__submit {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="pt-site-footer__submit">
  <input type="email" placeholder="Your e-mailadress" />
  <button>LOGIN</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you need

```css
.pt-site-footer__submit{
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
input {
  background: #8196aa;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  min-width: 320px;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  background: #16bdae;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 7px;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px;
  cursor:pointer;
  right: 5px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="pt-site-footer__submit">
  <input type="email" placeholder="Your e-mailadress">
  <button>LOGIN</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Please try to given css

button {
    background: #16bdae;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 7px;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 5px;
}

.pt-site-footer__submit {
    width: auto;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.pt-site-footer__submit{
      position: relative;

}
input {
        background: #8196aa;
        border: 0;
        border-radius: 10px;
        color: white;
        padding: 20px;
        width: 94%;

        &:focus {
            outline: none;
        }

        &::placeholder {
            color: white;
        }
    }

  button {
    background: #16bdae;
    border: 0;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 7px;
    color: white;
    padding: 6px 15px;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 38px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="pt-site-footer__submit">
  <input type="email" placeholder="Your e-mailadress">
  <button>LOGIN</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The input tag is a self closing, you cannot put children. Maybe you can add a wrapper element that you will should style as it was an input and set transparent background on your input. For instance:

```
<div class="pt-site-footer__submit">
   <div class="input-wrapper">
       <input type="email" placeholder="Your e-mailadress">
       <button>LOGIN</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

The style is something like this:

```
input {
    width: calc(100% - [BUTTON-WIDTH]);
    border: 0;
    color: white;
    background-color: transparent;

    &:focus {
        outline: none;
    }

    &::placeholder {
        color: white;
    }
}

button {
    width: [BUTTON-WIDTH];
    background: #16bdae;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 7px;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px;
}

input-wrapper {
    background: #8196aa;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

We can also use the flexbox or css grid to diagram and centering this component if you need

Answer (score 1):

Strictly you cannot put the button inside the input as an input element doesnt have content in that sense.

What you can do is position the button absolute and bring it back using a translate to overlay the input to give the same visual effect.

Here's a snippet that does that but you will have to think about how much padding to give and how much to bring the button back in order not to overwrite some of the placeholder.

```css
input {
  background: #8196aa;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

input::placeholder {
  color: white;
}

button {
  background: #16bdae;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 7px;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(calc(-100% - 5px), 5px);
}
```

```html
<div class="pt-site-footer__submit">
  <input type="email" placeholder="Your e-mailadress">
  <button>LOGIN</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

@Abin Thaha has provided a fine answer. I would make only one change to the css posted in that answer.

Add `padding-right: 100px;` to `input` css to prevent long text from flowing under the login button:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input {
  background: #8196aa;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  padding-right: 100px; /* <---------- Added right padding here to prevent text flowing under button */
  width: 100%;
}

input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

input::placeholder {
  color: white;
}

button {
  background: #16bdae;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 7px;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  top: 5px;
}

.pt-site-footer__submit {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="pt-site-footer__submit">
  <input type="email" placeholder="Your e-mailadress" />
  <button>LOGIN</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
input {
        background: #8196aa;
        border: 0;
        border-radius: 10px;
        color: white;
        padding: 20px;

        &:focus {
            outline: none;
        }

        &::placeholder {
            color: white;
        }
    }

    button {
        background: #16bdae;
        border: 0;
        border-radius: 7px;
        color: white;
        padding: 15px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="pt-site-footer__submit">
  <input type="email" placeholder="Your e-mailadress">
  <button>LOGIN</button>
</div>
```